# are there any ansible tower global variables like job id

Tags: variables, ansible

I am using Ansible tower 3.4.3. 
As part of one of my jobs, I need to generate a log file and logfile name should contain Tower_Job_ID to easily recognize which log is generated by which tower job id. 
I guess there will be some global variables like "**ansible_tower_job_id**" but unable to find any documentation or the variable name.

Can some one help, how to capture the current running job ID in ansible tower.

Answer (score 0):

The [callback](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/job_templates.html#provisioning-callbacks) link contains the ID in it.
From the docs: "The ‘1’ in this sample URL is the job template ID in Tower." .